# Searching for tags in Mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb, search, tags

I have 3 different collections, with different content in my script:
image, audio and video.

In each element I put in the database, I add a tag.

When I am trying to search for the tags (of the files I add each collection) I can only find the tags for the **image** collection:

-------------------------------CODE---------------------------------------------------

protected void search(String term) {

```
    tagCounter = 0;
    DBCollection image = db.getCollection("p");
    DBCollection audio = db.getCollection("a");
    DBCollection video = db.getCollection("video");

    String search = searchField.getText();
    search.trim().toLowerCase();    
    BasicDBObject tagQuery= new BasicDBObject();
    tagQuery.put("tags", search);

    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(tagQuery);
    tagQuery.put("tags", search);

                cursor = image.find(tagQuery);
                while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                     results.addElement( cursor.next().toString());
                     tagCounter++; 
                    searchField.setText(null);
                    }

                cursor = audio.find(tagQuery);
                while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                        results.addElement(cursor.next());
                         tagCounter++; 
                        searchField.setText(null);
                     }

                 cursor = video.find(tagQuery);    
                 while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                         results.addElement( cursor.next().toString()) ;
                         tagCounter++; 
                        searchField.setText(null);
                 }

                 JOptionPane counter = new JOptionPane();   
                counter.showMessageDialog(resultList, "Search gave " + tagCounter + " files");

                }
```

---

Can anyone help a newbie out? :)

Comment: Not sure this is the problem but it could be. The `search.trim().toLowerCase();` should be `search = search.trim().toLowerCase();`.  Could the tags in the database not have been properly normalized?

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly for me, except for the fact that you have a lot of references to things that are not declared/defined and also you are missing `.toString()` in the audio collection.

In a nutshell, the data is fetched the same way from all the collections, what you need to make sure that you do in your code is check what `searchField.setText(null);` line does - since you are getting things fine for the first collection but not the next two it tells me you are likely clearing something that's needed by the code.

Best thing to do is to use lots of "debugging" statements throughout, not just at the end.  Here is my simplified version of your code (I put one matching document in each collection):

```
int tagCounter = 0;
DBCollection image = db.getCollection("p");
DBCollection audio = db.getCollection("a");
DBCollection video = db.getCollection("video");
String search = "tag1";
search.trim().toLowerCase();
BasicDBObject tagQuery= new BasicDBObject();
tagQuery.put("tags", search);
DBCursor cursor = null;

cursor = image.find(tagQuery);
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println( cursor.next().toString());
     tagCounter++;
}
System.out.println(tagCounter + " matches found in image");

cursor = audio.find(tagQuery);
tagCounter = 0;
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println( cursor.next().toString());
     tagCounter++;
     }

System.out.println(tagCounter + " matches found in audio");

cursor = video.find(tagQuery);
tagCounter = 0;
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println( cursor.next().toString());
     tagCounter++;
 }
System.out.println(tagCounter + " matches found in video");
```

And my output is:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5186a59151058e0786e90eee"} , "tags" : [ "tag1" , "tag2"]}
1 matches found in image
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5186a59851058e0786e90eef"} , "tags" : [ "tag1" , "tag2"]}
1 matches found in audio
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5186a5a851058e0786e90ef0"} , "tags" : [ "tag1" , "tag2"]}
1 matches found in video
```